# how to find href and click the link using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to selenium and have difficulty in locating the element.

I want to scrape from google news. I can input the text and search for the results. Say I search for the news of Microsoft and it returns a list of news.

My ultimate goal is to click the links one by one and extract the content of the news of each link. But I'm now stuck on how to click the link.

when I right click the "inspect element", the link part is in the form of

[image]

I tried

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('l _HId')
browser.find_element_by_partial_link('/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=newssearch&amp')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h3/a')
```

but none of them worked. It all returned the error: unable to locate the element.Can anyone tell me why and how to locate the element?

I interact with firefox and use python 3.4 on windows 7. Another problem is that there is no "copy xpath" in firefox even though I installed firebug and firepath. The xpath above was copied from Chrome actually.

Comment: Being "new to Selenium", have you considered reading the manual? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you using java but i can give you the idea in c# (the syntax is little different but the idea is the same)

```
IList<IWebDriver> elements =  driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")); //Will give you all the links on page.
string link1Text = elements[0].Text //Will give you the text.   
string link1 = elements[0].GetAttribute("href"); // will give you the link url.
```

and so on...